# make text input boxes fit to mobile screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

So I built a web app with Ruby on Rails, and the styling is done with Bootstrap. Unfortunately, front end design is not my strong suite.

The app is hosted [here](http://wordcloud.ninja) and the source code is [on GitHub](https://github.com/awanninger/wordcloud-ninja)

I was able to position two text input boxes and an bout button in the middle of the main page. This looks great on a desktop, but on a mobile phone it looks tiny.

**Is it possible, using Bootstrap or Rails**, *(I would prefer to do it client side if possible)* **to make these text boxes and buttons re-size to fit a mobile phone screen?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `viewport` meta-tag in your `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Check out the basic template in the Bootstrap documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

Comment: So this doesn't do exactly what I need, but it's a start. By adding the viewport meta tag the form on my index page sizes to a mobile screen properly. However, now that this meta tag is present in the app, it causes my second page (which displays a wordcloud) to zoom in on that wordcloud drastically. This makes the wordcloud unreadable, and therefore the app unusable on mobile devices.

Comment: Well you only asked to "to make these text boxes and buttons re-size to fit a mobile phone screen". The HTML for your tagcloud is generated by jQCloud and that doesn't really like responsive layouts (see Github issue: https://github.com/lucaong/jQCloud/issues/31).

However, they mention redrawing on resizing in their wiki: https://github.com/lucaong/jQCloud/wiki/Resizing